# Neo4j-admin dump is failing

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to dump a database on Neo4j Desktop 3.5.0 with:

```
...\bin> neo4j-admin dump --database=graph.db --to=/backup/db1.dump
```

And getting

```
command failed: Active logical log detected, this might be a source of inconsistencies.
Please recover database before running the dump.
To perform recovery please start database and perform clean shutdown.
```

The [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin/) states that *"neo4j-admin must be invoked as the neo4j user in order to ensure the appropriate file permissions."*. Might that be the problem?

If so, how to *"invoke as the neo4j user"*?

Answer (score 10):

found workaround.

1. shutdown database
2. open terminal
3. run `bin/neo4j console`
4. after startup, hit Ctrl+C to shutdown database
5. then, run `neo4j-admin dump` respectivery

confirmed on Neo4j Desktop 1.1.15

Answer (score 0):

This may be a [known issue](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12119) in version 3.5.0.

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, I had visited the thread about the dump after load problem. 
But I can't dump at all and I'm not upgrading, it's my first time with Neo4j..

Guess I'll have to wait for the issue to be fixed.

Comment: You do not have the DB running when you try to dump, do you? Also, you may want to try 3.5.1.

Comment: It's not running. Where can I find 3.5.1? The about section says it's version 1.1.3

Comment: Do you mean version 1.1.13 of the [Neo4j Desktop](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-desktop/)? That version number is separate from the neo4j DB version. You can use the Desktop to install a neo4j DB with a new version, or upgrade your existing DB. I don't know if 3.5.1 would solve your problem, though.

Comment: The db folder is named installation-3.5.0.
I just tried to do the dump on PowerShell and now i'm getting:

Invoke-Neo4jAdmin dump --database=graph.db --to=\backup
command failed: unable to dump database: AccessDeniedException: C:\

Will try to install a 3.5.1 db

Comment: [This Windows help file](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2623670/access-denied-or-other-errors-when-you-access-or-work-with-files-and-f) may be instructive.

Comment: Got it! Don't know why but it worked when a file.dump was specified.

Thanks for the help @cybersam :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Neo4j 4.1, what worked for me was to simply:

- Stop the database
- Start the database
- Stop it again

After which `neo4j-admin dump` worked.
Credit for the solution to @folterj's last answer on [this thread](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/issues/12119).

Answer (score 0):

For me I was using different neo4j versions for creating (4.4.0) and dumping (4.2.6) the database